# Override property setter and getter

Tags: c#, .net, properties, attributes, custom-attributes

Is there a way to override the setter and getter of an auto property with an attribute?

like this:

```
[CustomAttribute]
public int Value { get; set; }
```

...

```
public class CustomAttibute : Attribute
{
    public override NotExistingPropertySetter(object value)
    {    
        if (((int)value) < 10 )
        {
            value = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. An attribute is never "executed". You would need to build a construct looking for the attribute and doing something if it's found.

AoP (aspect oriented programming) in .NET is only possible by using third party software like PostSharp.

Comment: Additionally, you might find that if your goal is just to not write the same property code more than once, you may be using the wrong abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will achieve this with AOP [image]

Comment: While this isn't exactly wrong, SO supports code directly, and sentences generally read better without an image in the middle of a four-letter word. (Or any word, for that matter!) I like your syntax highlighting, though.

Comment: You missed the fact that this is PostSharp, a third party tool the original poster may not have. After all, it is not exactly cheap.