# Implement property with custom attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Maybe I'm getting the Concept of Custom Attributes wrong, but I thought this should be something that would be possible:

I'm having a class with a  string property. I have multiple derived classes with properties that basically get a sub-string of the baseClass's property

```
class BaseClass {
     public string MyString { get; set;}
}

class FooClass : BaseClass {
     public string Part1 { get { return MyString.SubString(0,3); }}
     public string Part2 { get { return MyString.SubString(3,5); }}
}

class BarClass : BaseClass {
     public string PartA { get { return MyString.SubString(0,4); }}
     public string PartB { get { return MyString.SubString(4,1); }}
}
```

They also have a setters, and the real code is a little bit more complex... But you got the picture.

I would like to not have to implement this a thousand times, so I was thinking of using a custom attribute. So I could do:

```
class FooClass : BaseClass {
     [DataPart(0, Length = 3)]
     public string Part1 { get; set; }
     [DataPart(3, Length = 5)]
     public string Part2 { get; set; }
}

class BarClass : BaseClass {
     [DataPart(4, Length = 4)]
     public string PartA { get; set; }
     [DataPart(4)]
     public string PartB { get; set; }
}
```

I already have Custom Attribute for it:

```
[global::System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class DataPartAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ushort Position { get; private set; }
    public ushort Length { get; set; }

    public DataByteAttribute(ushort position)
    {
        Position = position;
    }
}
```

What now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code to process your custom DataPartAttribute by using reflection.

perhaps, you should think about using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

For ex)

```
[StringLength(100, MinimumLength =30)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

you can then use an instance of ObjectValidator to validate your object.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the attribute hijack the getter to return something custom, which is not possible to do with .NET alone.

Apparently you can do it with a product called PostSharp (see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733428/override-property-setter-and-getter/21733564#21733564)).

You could put code in the getter to look at the attribute and build the string accordingly, so that every property would have the exact same code. I suspect this is all that PostSharp would do. But it would perform worse than using `.Substring` in every getter.